# how to pass parameter to a query inside the other query in SSIS lookup component

Tags: ssis, subquery

In the middle of a transformation, I am creating col1, col2 and col3,col4,col5 from table abc.

[image]
then in one of the steps, I require to use col1, col2, col3,col4 and col5 data for a lookup component with below structure:

```
SELECT V_COVER_FLAG 
FROM PROD_EXT_BENEFIT
WHERE  BENEFIT_CODE = col5
AND PRODUCT_CODE IN (SELECT V_SEC_CODE FROM abc
                       WHERE Y_NO= col1
                         AND REN = col2
                         AND END = col3
                         AND NO = col4)
```

I usually convert these types of script as below and then match the columns with col1 to col5 in lookup component:

```
SELECT a.V_COVER_FLAG, a.BENEFIT_CODE ,b.Y_NO, b.REN , b.END , b.NO 
FROM PROD_EXT_BENEFIT a, abc b
WHERE PRODUCT_CODE = b.V_SEC_CODE
```

I want to check:
1- my approach is correct? I mean if the number of records is high then we might face the problem, however, this query just returns single line record.

2- if I want to go with the first approach how I can pass parameters? I tried to read the previous post like [(Previous solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3869887/how-to-create-a-dynamic-in-query-in-ssis-2008), but the problem is I am in the middle of a transformation and I cannot set the variable or I don't know how to do it in middle of the transformation.

I am looking forward to hearing from you.

Comment: I didn't understand. Please be more specific with your `data flow` ?

Comment: @PrabhatG:I added my dataflow, it may help you. can you tell me which part u didnt understand

Comment: I didn't understand why would you write that SQL query? I'm not actually getting gist of problem statement. Trying to read again now.

Comment: @PrabhatG: because I am not sure how to pass parameter to "SELECT V_SEC_CODE FROM abc
                       WHERE Y_NO= col1
                         AND REN = col2
                         AND END = col3
                         AND NO = col4)" col1,col2,col3 and col4

Comment: You can always choose to put your sql in variable and use in lookup. Like this: https://datasavvy.me/2015/12/28/using-a-variable-to-populate-the-query-in-a-lookup-in-ssis/

Comment: It is not clear to me how you want to use parameters in your lookup.   Please post the parameterized query you would like to use.   Does this help? https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+parameter+in+ssis+lookup&oq=how+to+use+parameter+in+ssis+lookup&aqs=chrome..69i57j0.5111j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Amir are you trying to set parameters based on the result of the Lookup or are you trying to use parameters value query constraint within the Lookup?

Comment: @JWeezy: nice question, I am not sure how to simulate this situation therefore I thought of using parameter to pass a value to my loopup query. but the problem is I am in "Data flow" mode and the previous way of creating parameter is not applicable.

Comment: @Amir The only way you can set parameter values in the data flow is in a script component. Note: you can use the row count function to set parameter values for row counts in the data pipeline only, but I doubt you are trying to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can set parameter values in the data flow is in a script component. So, run the lookup and then add a script component of type Transformation that sets the parameter values. For more information on modifying parameter values in script components, read: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/22198.use-ssis-variables-and-parameters-in-a-script-component.aspx

There is another way to do this and that is to create a custom data flow component. For more information on creating custom data flow components, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/data-flow/developing-a-custom-data-flow-component

Note: you can use the row count function to set parameter values for row counts in the data pipeline only, but I doubt you are trying to do this.